# show time like " 2 minutes ago"

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I'am beginner in yii2. I want to display how long ago the post created. I used bellow function to get it, but the result is just *0 Minutes ago*. can anyone help me?

```
<?php
function notifyDate($myStartDate) {
  $now = Yii::$app->jdate->date('Y/m/d') . '- ' . date('H:i:s');

  $datediff = $now - $myStartDate;
  if ($datediff < (60 * 60)) {  // Minutes
      return floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)) . " Minutes ago ";
  }
  if ($datediff < (60 * 60 * 24)) {  // Hours
      return floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)) . " Hours ago ";
  }
  // this  return the number of day
  return floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
}
?>

<?php
  $last_comment = Comment::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
  $myStartDate = $last_comment['created_time'];
  $now = Yii::$app->jdate->date('Y/m/d') . '-' . date('H:i:s');
?>

<span class="pull-right text-muted small">
    <em><?php echo notifyDate($myStartDate); ?></em>
</span>
```

Comment: check if you have a proper value in last_comment['created_time']; ,, try var:dump(last_comment['created_time'];);

Comment: I used the same code for submit created_time. its the bellow code.

$model->created_time = Yii::$app->jdate->date('Y/m/d') . '-' . date('H:i:s');

Comment: Have you tried to check the content of the posted value? what's the result?

Comment: created_time in database is: 1394/12/05-18:51:15, and value of $now is:1394/12/07-21:31:22

Answer (score 8):

For a more elegant display you can use

```
echo ( $timestampToDisplay < 60*60*24*365)
    ? Yii::$app->formatter->asRelativeTime($timestampToDisplay )
    : Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($timestampToDisplay );
```

This will display

- relative date values for timestamps less ago than a year
- absolute date values for timestamps longer ago than a year

Answer (score 3):

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asRelativeTime(time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no one helped me for this problem here , but I finally got useful function for the problem.
 Its very easy code for convert time to hour ,minutes and ... .
you just need to call function with crated time argument. and it returns how long the post has been submitted..

echo actionGetAgoTime($created_time);

function actionGetAgoTime($created_at) {

```
    $created_at = time() - $created_at; // to get the time since that moment
    $created_at = ($created_at < 1) ? 1 : $created_at;
    $tokens = array(
        31536000 => Yii::t('app', 'year'),
        2592000 => Yii::t('app', 'month'),
        604800 => Yii::t('app', 'week'),
        86400 => Yii::t('app', 'day'),
        3600 => Yii::t('app', 'hour'),
        60 => Yii::t('app', 'minute'),
        1 => Yii::t('app', 'second')
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($created_at < $unit)
            continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($created_at / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits . ' ' . $text . ' ' . Yii::t('app', 'ago');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use timeago jquery plugin for `Yii2`: https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-timeago. Notice that based in your question code, you use a library for Jalali calendar. For using timeage plugin, you need to convert your time Gregorian calendar. I suggest you to save your date with timestamp format and where you want to show date on fuzzy form, use this plugin like this:

```
// Suppose you pass $comment as an instance of Comment model to your view on controller.
<?= \yii\timeago\TimeAgo::tag(['timestamp' => date('c', $comment->created_time)]); ?>
```